# How to display data in different order from the same table using User Control that exists in many pages of the website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am trying to create a user control that helps me to **show data (from one table in the database) in different order in each page** in my web application.

For example, if it shows message#1 in this page as a first message then message#2 and so on, it should show message#10 as a first message in the other web page and so on.

My query is very simple like this:

```
SELECT MessageID, MessageDesc, MessageAuthor FROM [SafetyMessage]
```

By a help from my friend, I could be able to write the following code-behind:

```
public partial class MyMessageBoard : UserControl
    {

        public string Criteria
        {
            get
            {

                if (ViewState["Criteria"] != null)
                    return ViewState["Criteria"].ToString();
                    else
                        return " assign default criteria";

            }
            set {
                if (value != null)
                    ViewState["Criteria"] = value;
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DisplayMessage();
            }
        }

        private void DisplayMessage()
        {
            // Put your ADO.Net code that helps to select message based on the criteria
            // SELECT MessageID, MessageDesc, MessageAuthor FROM [SafetyMessage] WHERE Criteria
            // Execute the query and get the result
            // Finally display the result in the label control.
            // lblMessage.Text = "";
        }

    }
```

**Now, I want to retrieve the data from the table in the database and show it using Label control or repeater control. How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the filter criteria in WHERE condition correctly then you should be fine with what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get what you mean. Forgive me but as I said I am a new ASP.NET developer and there are many concepts that I need to learn and remember. If you see anything wrong in my code, please help me by correcting what I did.

Comment: My assumption: you have a set of records which need to be displayed in different order in different locations.
You can do it in SQL using ORDER BY clause. But this is only possible if you can sort your query in the way you want them to appear on each page.
Another way would be to sort the result in the code itself. How you can do it depends upon how you need to sort the messages. I need to know more detail about how you determine the order of those messages before I can provide you with any concrete answer. :)